# Similar questions to those marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-question

If a question is marked as duplicate, how can I find similar questions? Where is there tab I can tap on which will give the similar results?

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Meta. This is the place for all your website related questions so I migrated it over here.

When we close a question as a duplicate it tells you what we believe the duplicate is:

[image: Duplicate Link]

Beyond that there are Related Questions, these are automatically generated so not always very accurate:

[image: Related Questions]

There's also a search button on the top right (no idea where on Mobile, never use Mobile).

Comment: For the SE app, the search bar is at the top when you select a stack exchange.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Got that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Going along with Ryan's answer; You can find a lot of similar questions just by searching Google. Search: (Question you're looking for) Graphic Design Stack. This is usually how I find out if a question is duplicate or not.

Not sure if this is better than using this sites search function but I almost always find a duplicate in the first couple of search results if there is one.